# python requests module and connection reuse

Tags: python, python-requests, keep-alive

I am working with python's requests module for HTTP communication, and I am wondering how to reuse already-established TCP connections? The requests module is stateless and if I repeatedly call get for the same URL, wouldn't it create a new connection each time?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#keep-alive

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The requests module is stateless and if I repeatedly call get for the same URL, wouldnt it create a new connection each time?

The `requests` module is not stateless; it just lets you ignore the state and effectively use a global singleton state if you choose to do so.*

And it (or, rather, one of the underlying libraries, `urllib3`) maintains a connection pool keyed by (hostname, port) pair, so it will usually just magically reuse a connection if it can.

As [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#keep-alive) says:

> Excellent news — thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic
>   within a session! Any requests that you make within a session will
>   automatically reuse the appropriate connection!
>
> Note that connections are only released back to the pool for reuse
>   once all body data has been read; be sure to either set `stream` to
>   `False` or read the `content` property of the `Response` object.

So, what does "if it can" mean? As the docs above imply, if you're keeping streaming response objects alive, their connections obviously can't be reused.

Also, the connection pool is really a finite cache, not infinite, so if you spam out a ton of connections and two of them are to the same server, you won't *always* reuse the connection, just *often*. But usually, that's what you actually want.

---

<sub>* The particular state relevant here is the [transport adapter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#transport-adapters). Each session gets a transport adapter. You can specify the adapter manually, or you can specify a global default, or you can just use the default global default, which basically just wraps up a `urllib3.PoolManager` for managing its HTTP connections. For more information, read the docs.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response; this is really helpful. I have one more question. What is "session" in the above-mentioned documentation? I read through the document, and there actually is a Session object. I read through the "requests" code, and for each request a Session object is created. So, if connections are re-used only within a Session, then I am not sure how a connection will be reused between two "get" calls.

Comment: @gmemon: Sorry, that was bad wording. What I meant is the collection of adapters that make up the global state, in this case specifically the `HTTPAdapter` (which is the thing that holds the `urllib3.PoolManager`). I don't know what the right term for that is, but "session" is obviously a bad choice. I'll edit the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 120):

Global functions like `requests.get` or `requests.post` create the `requests.Session` instance on each call. Connections made with these functions cannot be reused, because you cannot access automatically created session and use it's connection pool for subsequent requests. It's fine to use these functions if you have to do just a few requests. Otherwise you'll want to manage sessions yourself.

Here is a quick display of `requests` behavior when you use global `get` function and session.

Preparation, not really relevant to the question:

```
>>> import logging, requests, timeit
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")
```

See, a new connection is established each time you call `get`:

```
>>> _ = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
>>> _ = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
```

But if you use the same session for subsequent calls, the connection gets reused:

```
>>> session = requests.Session()
>>> _ = session.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
>>> _ = session.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
>>> _ = session.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
>>> _ = session.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")
```

Performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('_ = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")', 'import requests', number=100)
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
...
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
52.74904417991638
>>> timeit.timeit('_ = session.get("https://www.wikipedia.org")', 'import requests; session = requests.Session()', number=100)
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.wikipedia.org
15.770191192626953
```

Works much faster when you reuse the session (and thus session's connection pool).

Comment: Might be the best answer which is available for the `requests` module, but it's still not satisfying since it's conflating connection reuse with session handling. Just because I want to share a connection between requests doesn't mean I want to share cookies etc. Best would be an option like `requests.enable_pooling()` to transparently enable pooling keyed by hostname and port (as the accepted answer wrongly suggest is the default).

Comment: You have a point, David Ongaro. However, this is an answer to a specific question about a specific library. The answer reflects the library implementation. What you are suggesting is out of scope of this question. I think that a better place to discuss your suggestion would be in the requests library bug tracker.