# Should I close the connection after each `requests.get` if I'm going to different pages of the same site?

Tags: python, python-requests, connection

So, I made a fun, experimental Python script that puts together a gobbledegook series of characters, then looks it up on the [Scrabble Dictionary](https://scrabblewordfinder.org/dictionary-checker) using the `requests` module. But this is the code snippet that I'm focusing on here:

```py
url = 'https://scrabblewordfinder.org/dictionary/'+word+'?s=t'
web = requests.get(url)
print('Found webpage')
# text = text[int(len(text)*0.75):]
if 'Not a valid word.' in web.text:
    print(''.join(word), 'is not a word')
else:
    print(''.join(word), 'is a word')
    words.append(word)
web.close()
```

(where `word` is the generated string of characters and `words` is the list of certified words)
(Oh, and all of that code is repeated over and over again in a loop.)

This code works fine, but I'm wondering if I have to close the connection each time. I don't really understand how websites work, but I think that when you visit a different page of the same website, you never close and re-open the connection to the server; it's just that what the server displays to you changes. (In fact, this is proven by the [URLs on Google Earth](https://earth.google.com/web/search/Tokyo,+Japan/@35.50924046,139.76981223,-0.80649054a,484444.36192196d,35y,0h,0t,0r/data=CncaTRJHCiUweDYwNWQxYjg3ZjAyZTU3ZTc6MHgyZTAxNjE4YjIyNTcxYjg5GfkoyHSN1kFAIb_nLFjPdGFAKgxUb2t5bywgSmFwYW4YAiABIiYKJAkwOv73espGQBE1Gpq_MAJFQBnUpCEpNTdcwCG7vrjDk-dewA); the application doesn't have to reload every time you move.)

So, do I cut out the `web.close` part and put it after the loop? If so, will `requests.get(`url`)` open a new connection each time, or simply change the information asked of the server without closing and reopening the connection?

P.S. I tried pre-searching for potential duplicates, but the [requests] tag has hundreds of matches and I don't know enough to narrow my search. Sorry if there are any duplicates! And thank you for any help!

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873927/python-requests-module-and-connection-reuse. The short version: use a `Session` object instead of `requests.get` to access the site.